# Limit the amount of buttons that can be a certain color vb

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've been creating this program but I only want 11 buttons to be backcolor lime? Is it possible? All I have is this code as I'm new to programming, I know it's not much but everything else I tried after this had an error.

```
       For Each control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
        If control.BackColor = Color.Lime Then

        End If
    Next
```

Below is the code for changing the button color in the first place, as one of the comments requested.

```
Private Sub btnLS_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLS.Click

    Static Dim btn_Count As Boolean = False

    If (btn_Count = True) Then
        btnLS.BackColor = Color.Red
        btn_Count = False
    Else
        btnLS.BackColor = Color.Lime
        btn_Count = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're saying you want the (now-empty) `If` body to be executed for up to 11 `Button`s where `BackColor` is `Lime`?  Or you want to change the `BackColor` from `Lime` for the 12th such `Button` onward?

Comment: @BACON I want no more than 11 buttons to be color lime, anything beyond that and the color will stay the same rather than changing to lime (I have the code for the changing color, I just want to limit the amount of buttons that can be that color)

Comment: @electricboy32 1) Does every button have basically the same code? 2) What is the purpose of the `btn_Count` variable?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the code provided is separate from that which sets the `BackColor` and is intended to revert the "limification" after the fact.  To limit which `Button`s will have their `BackColor` changed to only the 12th and beyond, you just need to introduce a counter variable...

```vb
Const LimeButtonLimit As Int32 = 11
Dim limeButtonCount As Int32 = 0

For Each button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
    If button.BackColor = Color.Lime Then
        limeButtonCount += 1
        If limeButtonCount > LimeButtonLimit Then
            button.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor
        End If
    End If
Next
```

When a `Lime` `Button` is found increment the count, and if it's greater than the limit, change the `BackColor`.  Note that I renamed the iterator variable from `control` to `button` to better reflect the fact that [`OfType(Of Button)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype) will yield instances of type `Button`.

Since you're already using LINQ you can use the [`Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) to only yield `Button`s where `BackColor` is `Lime`...

```vb
Const LimeButtonLimit As Int32 = 11
Dim limeButtonCount As Int32 = 0

For Each button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button).Where(Function(btn) btn.BackColor = Color.Lime)
    limeButtonCount += 1
    If limeButtonCount > LimeButtonLimit Then
        button.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor
    End If
Next
```

Finally, you can add the [`Skip()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip) so the body of the `For Each` is only executed for the 12th `Lime` `Button` onward, removing the need to count the `Button`s yourself...

```vb
Const LimeButtonLimit As Int32 = 11

For Each button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button).Where(Function(btn) btn.BackColor = Color.Lime).Skip(LimeButtonLimit)
    button.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor
Next
```

If there are 11 or less `Button`s with a `BackColor` of `Lime` the body of the loop will never be executed.